# The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have submitted many app builds to TestFlight, even yesterday, but today when I tried to submit my app to TestFlight via XCODE I get the following error:

`ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: '[ ]' for the key 'com.apple.developer.healthkit.access' in 'Payload/Runner.app/Runner'."`

I'm building a flutter project via XCODE. I have tried the following:

- Cleaning my project.
- Re-enabling automatic app signing in XCODE.
- Deleting my provisioning files from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
- Disabling automatic signing in xcode and creating my own provisioning profile via the Apple Developer site

But I'm still getting this error. My enablements haven't changed from the last time I uploaded my app. Please help, thank you.

**UPDATE 1**:
Appears to be a change made on Apples end that is causing this error. No official response/explanation from Apple has been provided yet. Some workarounds have been provided below. I went with enabling Clinical Health Records usage for the Health Kit enablement since this workaround doesn't use any non-apple approved changes. So still technically not a final solution, but a workaround.

**UPDATE 2**:
Apple has resolved the issue on their end, no workarounds are required anymore.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but with `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers` key. Moreover, the build I uploaded never reached App Store Connect after 40 minutes

Comment: It seems Apple has fixed the bug on their end, I just uploaded a build with the empty com.apple.developer.healthkit.access key/value untouched and build was uploaded to TestFlight just fine, as of now 0:00 23-Jan +10, from down under.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has fixed the issue. You can now try submitting app to TestFlight without making any changes.

Thread on Apple Developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671352

Answer (score 17):

#### Solution

What worked for me was to remove the following line in the `.entitlements` file

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
<array/>
```

#### Validation

- I double checked and the **HealthKit** access still works for read/write when building via Xcode
- I tested the app via **TestFlight** and everything still looks good
- My app got approved and everything works fine for existing and new users :)

#### Side notes

- I had the same issue. I haven’t changed the entitlements for months and out of a sudden that error appeared. It might be the case that Apple changed some logic and applied stricter rules on their backend entitlement validation.
- Interesting that if you create a new Xcode project and add the HealthKit entitlements it creates the entitlements like:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
<array/>
```

- Interesting read: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/10738

Comment: as doing like this i can able to upload build. but binary got rejected due to, ITMS-90034: Missing or invalid signature - The bundle 'appid' at bundle path 'Payload/XXX.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate.

Comment: devleoper.apple Link is broken

Comment: I believe you need to remove the line under that as well: `<array/>`, otherwise it's an invalid plist.

Comment: Hi, I am just about to apply the solution to my project, just wondering if your app got approved by apple? thanks!

Comment: Yes the app got approved and works perfectly on the AppStore :) -> sorry forgot to update the post -> will do it now

Answer (score 17):

I was facing the similar error.

I believe the Apple back-end has changed and has started applying a stricter rule to entitlement keys that take array values.

I believe the Apple back-end used to accept empty arrays for entitlement keys that took array values but now require the entitlement key to either not be present at all or to contain actual values.

Evidence to back this assertion:

- I have an entitlements file with a key for "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers" entitlement with an empty array like so:

```
  <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
  <array/>
```

- This was fine until just yesterday (I successfully submitted a build, and have submitted builds like this for more than a year).

---

**The Fix:**

Remove or Comment out the following line from the `.entitlements` file:

```
  <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
  <array/>
```

- The key was empty anyway so should not have an effect after being removed.

Now the TestFlight submission is successful.

Comment: This did not work for healthkit access. Breaks the integration and app is no longer able to read healthkit data.

Answer (score 12):

Remove 'com.apple.developer.healthkit.access' won't help the issue. So far we can just hope to wait for Apple to fix this.

Thread on forum (i can't access the Marceeelll's thread):
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671352

Related:

- [App Store Connect Operation Error: ITMS-90164 [] for key com.apple.developer.healthkit.access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712473/app-store-connect-operation-error-itms-90164-for-key-com-apple-developer-hea)

Comment: Haven't seen this thread. But bricepollock1 suggested to do the same as I proposed. Whats wrong with it? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671352?answerId=656525022#656525022

Comment: @Marceeelll you can read those comments in the thread, the solution only help some people who get this error. Many new issues appear after applying this solution, like invalid bundle (in the related post) , can't get Apple Health permissons or the build doesn't show up on Testflight

Comment: This isn't a solution, yes it allows you to build and upload but renders the bundle invalid.

Comment: @Marceeelll  removing the key broke my healthkit integration entirely.

Answer (score 11):

For me solution is to remove the following line in the .entitlements file

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
<array/>
```

**!This work if you submit the app for TestFlight!**

This does not work if you submit the app for review :(. Binary will be rejected ITMS-90000: This bundle is invalid - $message.

What work for me: First, when you enable your app’s HealthKit capabilities: you must also select the Clinical Health Records checkbox!

[image]

Next, you must provide a Health Records Usage string in your app’s Info.plist file.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Same error for me with "icloud-container", just comment these lines in your . entitlements file:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.[YOUR-ERROR]</key>
<array/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Deleting the empty iCloud Container entitlement (array) from the entitlement files solved the issue for me. Seems like a server-side change from Apple that no longer allows an empty array there.

Answer (score 4):

**What worked for me**

Before started trying, I checked my `.entitlements` file it looks like this:

```xml
    ...
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
    <array/>
    ...
```

**Step 1**: Remove and add HealthKit capability again.

- Remove HealthKit from "Signing and Capabilities"

[image]

- Add HealthKit back

[image: 2]

**Step 2**: Check on "Clinical Health Records"

[image: 3]

Once done, you shall be able to see your `.entitlements` file become

```xml
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
    <array>
        <string>health-records</string>
    </array>
```

**Step 3**: Add `Privacy - Health Records Usage Description` and its value to `info.plist`

**Final**: Then I tried to archive and upload to TestFlight, it worked.

Comment: :) I add the same before you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712249/the-entitlements-in-your-app-bundle-signature-do-not-match-the-ones-that-are-con/65725769#65725769

Answer (score 3):

I commented-out/removed

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
```

in .entitlements and it works!

Answer (score 2):

A key with a value that is an empty array seems to be not allowed in entitlements anymore. Just removing the key/value pair fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I had the same issue with Network extensions, it is also empty and deleting it from Entitlements solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the empty iCloud container entitlement will resolve the upload issue. But the app cannot select any documents from iCloud using document picker (UIDocumentMenuViewController).

We would end up with a crash in the app as below:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application initializing
> document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is
> com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?'