# App Store Connect Operation Error: ITMS-90164 [] for key com.apple.developer.healthkit.access

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, healthkit

I am now getting this error when trying to upload to the app store, but I haven't made any changes to my healthkit capability and it everything looks fine (see images).  Why is it saying the value is `[]` [image]

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
    <array/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.codes.myndarc.newFitnessApp</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
    <array>
        <string>CloudKit</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>group.com.myndarc.newFitnessApp</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image]

Comment: You *do* have an empty array for `com.apple.developer.healthkit.access`, as the error states.  You should remove this key since you don't need access to clinical records and your provisioning profile doesn't have the HealthKit capabilities entitlement

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but with `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers`

Comment: I am facing same issue after deleting com.apple.developer.healthkit.access binary got rejected also

Comment: This works for me now -- looks like Apple fixed the bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following line in the .entitlements file

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
<array/>
```

This not work :(. Binary will be rejected `ITMS-90000: This bundle is invalid - $message.`

**What work for me:**
First, when you enable your app’s HealthKit capabilities: you must also select the Clinical Health Records checkbox!
[image]

Next, you must provide a Health Records Usage string in your app’s Info.plist file.
[image]

Comment: I think if you delete this line you are also deleting your HealthKit capability

Comment: Yes and binary got rejected due to ITMS-90034: Missing or invalid signature

Comment: **!This work if you submit the app for TestFlight!** 

This does not work if you submit the app for review :(. Binary will be rejected ITMS-90000: This bundle is invalid - $message. But I add more info about rejection fix. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712473/app-store-connect-operation-error-itms-90164-for-key-com-apple-developer-hea/65725753#65725753

Comment: This didn't seem to work a few days ago, but today I removed `<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
<array/>` and was able to submit

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't change our code too much, this appears to be something on Apple's end that hopefully they'll fix soon.  https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: As of 5:30pm EST the system status page says that it's been resolved, but I still see the same errors when attempting to upload.

Comment: Anyone coming to this I would encourage you to file a Feedback with Apple

Comment: Having the same issue and fixed it by editing .entitlements file in a text editor and removing the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifier key.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
It looks like Apple fixed this issue yesterday (January 21, 2021). I don't see the error anymore.

---

I have the same issue. If I read that error correctly it fails because the value for `com.apple.developer.healthkit.access` is different in the App Store provisioning profile and in the entitlements file.

And it's indeed different.

When I enable HealthKit capability from Xcode, it adds this to the entitlements file:

```
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
    <array/>
```

When I create an App Store provisioning profile from https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list, then download it and open it with a text editor I see this:

```
                <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
        <true/>
                <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
        <array>
                <string>health-records</string>
        </array>
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to set what the provisioning profile sets for `com.apple.developer.healthkit.access`, so it looks like the only way to make them have the same value is to enable "Clinical Health Records" HealthKit capability from Xcode, so that it adds it to the entitlements file too. This doesn't sound like the right solution, since it forces you to enable "Clinical Health Records" even if you don't use it. It looks to me like this is a recent change on Apple's side that changed how the value from the entitlement file is compared to the one in the provisioning profile, as it didn't happen before and I didn't change neither the entitlements file nor the provisioning profile since the last successful app release.

Removing `com.apple.developer.healthkit.access` key from entitlements file is, in my opinion, also not a correct solution since the HealthKit capability is removed in "Signing & Capabilities" UI from Xcode when you do that. And also I see here some people reported that the app does not pass the App Store review when you do that. Also it's Xcode that adds that to entitlements when HealthKit capability is added, why would we need to remove that manually?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with *com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers*.
and I checked the box containers at **Signing and capabilities -> icloud,** then the problem has been resolved

example:
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same issue. Adding "health-records" to the entitlements file combined with the NSUsage description in the plist file will work fine for sure, but still is a workaround. As we do not want to access clinical health records, nor to have that displayed somewhere (App Store) this is not a solution for us.
Does anybody no whether this change will be displayed somewhere, e.g. in the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

`2021-01-22T02:34:25.810Z` : TestFlight did not reject my build including

```
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
    <array/>
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like Apple fixed it yesterday.