# Getting ERROR ITMS-90164 when trying to upload Watch App to AppStore

Tags: swift, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

I am learning to develop an Apple WatchOS App (stand alone watch app), this is my first ever app, I have written the code to access the HealthKit functionality (Read and Write, I am also able to run the app on my physical device and no errors in console when reading or writing to HealthKit).

**I have created an Identifier in the Apple Developer Website and enabled HealthKit**
[image]

**In my app I have also enabled the HealthKit Capabilities**
[image]

In my Info.plist I have added the following 2 permissions

- Privacy - Health Share Usage Description
- Privacy - Health Update Usage Description

However I am getting the following error when trying to publish the app to AppStore.

Please can someone guide me and tell me what I could be doing wrong here.

My Error
App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: '[ ]' for the key 'com.apple.developer.healthkit.access' in 'Payload/app name.app/Watch/app name WatchKit App.app/PlugIns/app name WatchKit Extension.appex/app name WatchKit Extension'."

I have tried to run ***Product->Clean*** etc however no luck

Thank you

Comment: Hi, sorry no it does not, I tried everything from that thread

Comment: Please keep in mind I am using Native Swift and my app is Watch Only App

Comment: I'm in the same boat -- pretty sure this is a bug in AppStoreConnect.

Comment: @LouFranco please let me know if you find a fix

Comment: there is a solution that is closely related to the above issue, please see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65715248/997562

Comment: It now just works for me as it did before with no changes.  Apple seems to have fixed their bug @BillyMahmood